# Validation of code

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed some code in bootstrap and I am getting an error while I was validating the fields (name, email). Please help me out.

This is the code for the form:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="text-center">CONTACT</h3>
  <p class="text-center"><em>I love my Fans!</em></p>
  <div class="row test">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>4429, Rainier Street, Irving, Texas ,United States</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>Phone:Phone</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>Email: Email</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form control" id="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" onBlur="txt_Blur(this,'errorName')" />
          <span id="errorName" style="display:none;">Please enter a valid name!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
          <span id="errorName" style="display:none;">Please enter a valid email!</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="textarea">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea>
        <span id="errorName" style="display:none">Please enter your comments!</span>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
          <button class="btn pull-right" type="submit" onclick="button_Click()">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript for validation below:

```
function txt_Blur(ref, errorId) {
  if (ref.value == "") {
    document.getElementById(errorId).style = "color:red;";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(errorId).style = "display:none;";
  }
}

function button_Click() {
  if (document.getElementById("name")).value == "") {
    document.getElementById("errorName").style = "color:red;";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("errorName").style = "display:none;";
  }
  if (document.getElementById("email")).value == "") {
    document.getElementById("errorName").style = "color:red;";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("errorName").style = "display:none;";
  }
}
```

I need the error displayed when someone tries to leave the name field empty and goes to the next text field (email).

Comment: So, what's the error ?

Comment: The id what you r using repeatedly .. so first thing avoid it ... then the second thing just use the HTML5 validation and most of the problems r solved there.